# Any thought to moving away from Quantserve for tracking purposes on WPSE?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

Maybe it's just me, and maybe because WPSE is my home page, but whenever I visit the site my computer hangs waiting for the tracking cookies to be processed.  It's an annoyance, because when I want to use the browser, I want to use it.

I could block the cookies, but that would have unintended consequences (both for me for WPSE)--particularly inability for accurately tracking use of a valuable site. The issues around Quantserve traffic congestion and processing cookies are fairly well documented.

Is this a real issue or am I just looking for something to be allergic to?

Comment: I do not experience such issue. Could you please add technical details, such as browser you are using and how had you narrowed it down to cookies processing?

Comment: Same here, I don't suffer the issue your are experiencing.

Comment: Happens most frequently on FF (8.0), Windows 7.  Occasionally on Chrome (15.0.874.121).  When the browser launches, you can see that it is trying to connect first to edge.quantserve.com, then loads wordpress.stackexchange.com.  When I looked up Quantserve, there were many articles and discussions on the impact it has had on other sites as well, related to inbound traffic to their servers.  It's not a major issue, as it hasn't crashed the browser (as it has for some others), but it slows loading the site between 5-10 seconds at times.

Comment: I suffer from the same issues on FF, Ray. 9.0, Windows XP. It really does slow the loading of WPSE, especially when I'm at work on a less-than-optimal internet connection.

Comment: @dunc - I stopped using it as a home page on FF, and leave it as my Chrome home page.